# Inherit from DelegateCommand without using static properties

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container

How can i avoid static Propertys in this bit of Code:

```
public class RoleCommand : RoleBaseCommand, IRoleCommand
{
    #region Properties
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
    public static IMitarbeiterRepository Repository { get; set; }
    public static IInformation Information { get; set; }


    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public RoleCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod = null, string roleName = null,
        IUnityContainer container = null)
        : base(executeMethod, () => canExecuteMethod == null ? HasRecht() : HasRecht() && canExecuteMethod(), roleName)
    {
        if (executeMethod == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleName) && container == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Der UnityContainer darf nicht null sein wenn der RoleName gefüllt ist.");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleName) && container != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "Der RoleName darf nicht null sein wenn der IUnityContainer nicht null ist.");


        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleName) && container != null)
        {
            Container = container;
            Repository = container.Resolve<IMitarbeiterRepository>();
            Information = container.Resolve<IInformation>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gibt an ob der Mitarbeiter das Recht hat diese Aktion auszuführen.
    /// </summary>
    protected static bool HasRecht()
    {
        return Repository.HasMitarbeiterARoleWith(RoleName, Information.CurrentMitarbeiter);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The class RoleBaseCommand inherit from DelegateCommand of the Unity/Prism framework for WPF. Also I use Dependency Injection.

Only if the HasRecht() method returns true I want to execute the command.

Comment: What you want to do is not really clear. I tried to put together a couple of examples, but wasn't able to without knowing what you are wanting here. Provide an example of how the `RoleCommand` is instanced, an example of when `HasRecht` is used so that we can have a better idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Instanciate: `new RoleCommand(SaveChangesExecuteMethod, roleName: "EditMitarbeiter", container: container);` The Method HasRecht returns bool if a person have the right to execute the command.